# No newline after mdframed title (i.e. inline title)

Tags: theorems, mdframed

I'm using `mdframed` for all my theorem-like environments. By default, `mdframed` titles appear above the body. I want one of my `mdtheorem` environments to start the body on the same line as the title, which is the behaviour of LaTeX's default `newtheorem` command.

(For search engines: that means I want an inline title, so no newline after the title.) I couldn't find the right option for this in the documentation of the frame title.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdtheorem[font=\slshape, linewidth=1pt]{exercise}{Exercise}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
Sketch a decider machine for the halting problem.
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run-in titles are the default if you use `\newmdtheorem` instead:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdtheorem[font=\slshape, linewidth=1pt]{exercise}{Exercise}[section]

\newmdtheoremenv[linewidth=1pt]{exercisetwo}{Exercise}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
Sketch a decider machine for the halting problem.
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercisetwo}
Sketch a decider machine for the halting problem.
\end{exercisetwo}

\end{document}
```

However, as you can see the default also use the italic font rather than the slanted.  Adding `font=\slshape` will also change the shape of the heading `Exercise` which you probably do not want.  Loading the `amsthm` package, *before* `mdframed`, gives the chance to define new styles, see the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm).  For example, a slanted font, with no vectical space before the title and no punctuation after the title is given by defining a `myexercise` style and used in `exercisethree`:

[image: Second sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdtheorem[font=\slshape, linewidth=1pt]{exercise}{Exercise}[section]

\newmdtheoremenv[linewidth=1pt]{exercisetwo}{Exercise}[section]

\newtheoremstyle{myexercise}{-\topsep}{}{\slshape}{}{\bfseries}{}{.5em}{}
\theoremstyle{myexercise}
\newmdtheoremenv[linewidth=1pt]{exercisethree}{Exercise}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
Sketch a decider machine for the halting problem.
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercisetwo}
Sketch a decider machine for the halting problem.
\end{exercisetwo}

\begin{exercisethree}
Sketch a decider machine for the halting problem.
\end{exercisethree}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Would've never guessed the subtle difference. If I may ask: if I nest `exercisethree` in a regular `\mdtheorem` (let's say `\mdtheorem[topline=false,bottomline=false,rightline=false,linewidth=1.25pt]{example}{Example}[section]`) in the document, it not only inherits that outer frame's style (the exercise loses three sides), but the outer environment's title is also copied overtop the title of `exercisethree`. This doesn't happen when nesting `exercisethree` into itself. I guess adding `default` before `linewidth=...` is one solution to prevent this. Is there a better one?

Comment: That doubling is strange.   I guess you would want to wrap an ordinary theorem with the given style `\theoremstyle{myexercise}\newtheorem{exercisefour}{Exercise}[section]` instead.